# Where should we add general or topic-specific help pages and guides?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions

I and some of the other frequent answers in the Perl ghetto of StackOverflow have been linking to external sites to show people how to ask good questions that can lead to better answers. I don't know if the other areas have similar problems, but the Perl questions come from a very inexperienced crowd.

[drewk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298607/drewk) spent a lot of time in [one answer guiding the poster](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3737430/8817).

We also tend to link to:

- [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341)
- [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

I'd like to digest and reorganize all of this into a StackOverflow page, on the main site or on meta, that has all the wiki goodness, etc, of this site. I didn't readily find one if it already exists.

Some topics might also have more specialized help pages, which would be a nice addition to the topic wikis. The "faq" topic link is too disorganized to serve as a guide.

Comment: Related: An (currently disputed) initiative of using the question format for a better tag wiki in the PHP tag: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php-closed)

Answer (score 2):

Someone with sufficient reputation in the perl tag could edit the [tag-specific wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl/info).

Comment: I'm not so worried about the topic stuff. The tag wiki doesn't seem like a good solution since it ends up as a dumping ground for everything for that tag (unless I somehow missed how to create sub pages). I could also link offsite, but then that's not what I'm after.